# Which GATT service does the Date Time GATT characteristic belong to?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

Bluetooth specifications define a [Date Time GATT characteristic](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.date_time.xml)... but I couldn't find a GATT service to which it is related. Did I miss something in the GATT specifications ? Would there be something like characteristics that could be used by all services ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is definitely not a "super-characteristic" that could be used by all services. Also, there is, at least to my knowledge, no service that would implement this characteristic directly. It seems to be simply a type definition.

For example, take the Continuous Glucose Monitoring Service and its characteristic [Session Start Time](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.cgm_session_start_time.xml): The value field "Session Start Time" is of type org.bluetooth.characteristic.date_time.

Interestingly, on the Nordic homepage, it is listed as a [Bluetooth Service](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/documentation/nrf51/4.3.0/html/group__ble__sdk__srv.html). But there they also only describe it as "Definition of ble_date_time_t type" without any functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does GATT specs allow to customize a  standard service by adding a standard characteristic to it... or do we have to create a custom service for that ?

Comment: Standard services - like Continuous Glucose Monitoring (CGM) service - have to be implemented exactly as defined by the Bluetooth specifications. This is to ensure interoperability between different devices; if one device exposes the CGM service, the other device can rely on the operation of the service as specified. If you want to add a new characteristic, you will have to create a custom service for that.